# Print number of characters in UTF-8 string

Tags: utf-8, lua

For example:

```
local a = "Lua"
local u = "Луа"
print(a:len(), u:len())
```

output:

```
3   6
```

How can I output number of characters in utf-8 string?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need to use Unicode/UTF-8 in Lua, you need to use external libraries, because Lua only works with 8-bit strings. One such library is [slnunicode](https://github.com/LuaDist/slnunicode). Example code how to calculate the length of your string:

```
local unicode = require "unicode"
local utf8 = unicode.utf8

local a = "Lua"
local u = "Луа"
print(utf8.len(a), utf8.len(u)) --> 3    3
```

Answer (score 3):

In Lua 5.3, you can use [`utf8.len`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-utf8.len) to get the length of a UTF-8 string:

```
local a = "Lua"
local u = "Луа"
print(utf8.len(a), utf8.len(u))
```

Output: `3  3`

Answer (score 2):

You don't.

Lua is not Unicode aware. All it sees is a string of bytes. When you ask for the length, it gives you the length of that byte string. If you want to use Lua to interact in some way with Unicode strings, you have to either write a Lua module that implements those interactions or download such a module.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to wrap the native os UTF-8 string functions and use the os functions to do the heavy lifting. This depends on which OS you use - I've done this on OSX and it works a treat. Windows would be similar. Of course it opens another can of worms if you just want to run a script from the command line - depends on your app.